# How to occur unentered data in the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a view page.Here i enter the contact no in the usual way using codeigniter.But the database shows a default number in each insertion.

Validation is in this way

```
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_contact', 'Employee Contact', 'required|numeric|min_length[10]|max_length[11]');
```

post the data in the usual way

```
          $emp_contact=$this->input->post('emp_contact');
```

i enter a number like 9632584147 and so on..But the inserted value inthe db always same no 2147483647

I post an answer.that way i got the correct value.But What's the reason?

Comment: Don't understand your issue. Its not clear . can you share more details or code .

Comment: what is your query to save ?

Comment: public function insertemployee($emp_name,$emp_contact)
    {
     $data=array(
     'emp_name'=>$emp_name,
      'emp_contact'=>$emp_contact,
     );
     $this->db->insert('employee_details',$data);   
    }

Comment: its seem ok..can you print value of $emp_contact befor this query and see what is the output of $emp_contact.
also print data value

Comment: ok. Print $this->db->last_query() after insert statement and see the query and fire same query on mysql and check

Comment: that shows the same problem..

Comment: can you paste the query here also result of $data

Comment: INSERT INTO `employee_details` (`emp_name`, `emp_contact`) VALUES ('Ram', '9563214786')

Comment: also paste create table query for employee_details .Might be there is some defualt  value set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number 2,147,483,647 (or hexadecimal 7FFF,FFFF16) is the maximum positive value for a 32-bit signed binary integer in computing.

What you was getting it is the max value of int i.e `2147483647`. To save greater then this value please use `bigint` instead of `int`.